# Expo get location updates in the background, not receiving updates

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, location

I am trying to get the location in the background and then send it to my server, I followed every stackoverflow answer and the official guides but for me the updates just aren't happening. I have a simple setup, using Expo SDK 48, and the official `expo-task-manager` with `expo-location`

So I have a component that encapsulates this logic, its called `LocationTracker` and via a `useLocationTracker` hook I wrap the logic

Here's the actual logic
`useLocationTracker.ts`

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import * as Location from "expo-location";
import { LatLng } from "react-native-maps";
import * as TaskManager from "expo-task-manager";
import { LocationObject } from "expo-location";
import { logger } from "../logger";
type Callback = (coords: LatLng) => void;
const LOCATION_TRACKING_TASK = "location_tracking_task";

const executor: (body: TaskManager.TaskManagerTaskBody<object>) => void = (
    body
) => {
    const data = body.data as unknown as { locations: LocationObject[] };
    const l = data?.locations[0];
    console.log("location", l);
    if (!l) return;

    for (const callback of Object.values(locationCallbacks)) {
        callback({
            latitude: l.coords.latitude,
            longitude: l.coords.longitude,
        });
    }
};

TaskManager.defineTask(LOCATION_TRACKING_TASK, executor);

const locationCallbacks: { [key: string]: Callback } = {};

function addLocationCallback(callback: Callback) {
    const id = uuid() as string;
    locationCallbacks[id] = callback;
    return {
        remove: () => {
            delete locationCallbacks[id];
        },
    };
}

export const useLocationTracker = (
    callback: Callback | null,
    active: boolean = true
) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!active) return;
        if (!callback) return;
        startTrackingLocation();
        const subscription = addLocationCallback(callback);
        return () => {
            subscription.remove();
            stopTrackingLocation();
        };
    }, [callback, active]);

    async function startTrackingLocation() {
        const { status: foregroundStatus } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
        if (foregroundStatus === 'granted') {
            const { status: backgroundStatus } = await Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync();
            if (backgroundStatus === 'granted') {
                try {
                    logger.info("starting location updates");
                    Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TRACKING_TASK, {
                        showsBackgroundLocationIndicator: true,
                        accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Highest,
                        distanceInterval: 10, // minimum change (in meters) betweens updates
                        deferredUpdatesInterval: 1000, // minimum interval (in milliseconds) between updates
                        timeInterval: 3000,
                        // foregroundService is how you get the task to be updated as often as would be if the app was open
                        foregroundService: {
                            notificationTitle: 'Using your location',
                            notificationBody: 'To turn off, go back to the app and switch something off.',
                        },
                    });
                } catch (e) {
                    logger.error("failed to start location updates", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    async function stopTrackingLocation() {
        Location.hasStartedLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TRACKING_TASK).then((value) => {
            if (value) {
                logger.info("stopping location updates");
                Location.stopLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TRACKING_TASK);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here's the component (very barebones)

`LocationTracker.tsx`

```js
import { api } from "@employees/lib/api";
import { useLocationTracker } from "@employees/lib/hooks/useLocationTask";
import { logger } from "@employees/lib/logger";
import { useAppStore } from "@employees/lib/store";
import { Point } from "@safedriver/db";
import { useCallback } from "react";

export const LocationTracker = () => {
    const { mutate, isLoading, isError } = api.employee.updateLocation.useMutation({
        onSuccess: (data) => {
            logger.info(new Date(), "updateLocation success", data)
        }
    })

    const callback = useCallback((location: Point) => {
        console.log("update location", location)
        mutate({ location })
    }, [mutate, shift]);

    useLocationTracker(callback, true)

    return null;
}
```

And this component is used in my `_layout.tsx` like so

```js
export default function Layout() {
    return (
        <TRPCProvider>
            <LocationTracker />
            <SafeAreaProvider>
                <Stack screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} />
                <StatusBar />
            </SafeAreaProvider>
        </TRPCProvider>
    );
}
```

I tested to check whether or not the Task is registered and running and it is, so that isn't the cause of the issue. My setup is the same as the top answers on stack overflow, my only concern is that my setup with the hook and the component isn't working because of some weird rerendering issue or something, as the code itself for the location tracking should be correct.

Why I consider the issue of rerendering is because I am constantly getting this logged

```
 LOG  [INFO] 53:52.699 Main - stopping location updates
 LOG  [INFO] 53:52.701 Main - starting location updates
 LOG  [INFO] 53:57.738 Main - stopping location updates
 LOG  [INFO] 53:57.740 Main - starting location updates
 LOG  [INFO] 54:03.2 Main - stopping location updates
 LOG  [INFO] 54:03.4 Main - starting location updates
 LOG  [INFO] 54:08.27 Main - stopping location updates
 LOG  [INFO] 54:08.29 Main - starting location updates
 LOG  [INFO] 54:13.81 Main - stopping location updates
 LOG  [INFO] 54:13.84 Main - starting location updates
 LOG  [INFO] 54:18.111 Main - stopping location updates
 LOG  [INFO] 54:18.113 Main - starting location updates
```

Comment: Commenting to track this answer. I have a similar issue!